# SearchView for more than 1 recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

Hi i have a **view pager** with **7 tabs** and inside all of them is one **recyclerview** i want to add Search for all of them.
i tried to add all of them into one recycler view for search but i really don't know how to do that.
any one can give me some tips to how do it?
i want to add a Search Dialog to my code and a single recycler View with all of my items this is possible?
 **and also all of my recyclerViews have there own Adapter and Parser and Model all of them is different with each Other**

Here is the code :

**RecyclerView Adapter Class :**

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {


public SearchAdapter(Context context,int code) {
    this.code = code;
    this.context = context;
}
private Context context;
private int code;
private View view;
@Override
public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (code){
        case 1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 2:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_layout,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 3:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.last_world_memes_list_item,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 4:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ex_list_tours_child,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 5:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.last_url_view,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 6:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.twitch,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
    }
    return new SearchViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (code){
        case 1:

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //Events
    AppCompatTextView timeEvent ,tvPrizeEvent ,tvGameModeEvent ,tvBuyInEvent ,tvLateRegEvent
            ,tvSiteEvent ;
    AppCompatImageView ivEvent ;
    LinearLayout layoutEvent ;
    //Sites
    TextView tvSites;
    RelativeLayout headerImageSites;
    AppCompatImageView btnRevilSites;
    AppCompatTextView infoTvSites;
    AppCompatTextView infoDateSites;
    AppCompatButton btnUrlSites;
    AppCompatButton btnTelegramSites;
    AppCompatButton btnSupportSites;
    RelativeLayout layoutSites;
    AppCompatButton btnRegSites;
    LinearLayout layour_btnSites;
    RelativeLayout parentLayoutSites;
    //Tours
    RelativeLayout layoutTours ;
    SharedPreferences preferencesTours ;
    AppCompatTextView timeTourTours  ,tvPrizeTours  ,tvGameModeTours ,tvBuyInTours ,tvLateRegTours
            ,tvReBuyTours ,tvDaysTours;
    Clock clockTours ;
    //Memes
    AppCompatImageView ivMemes;
    AppCompatTextView tvIvMemes;
    AppCompatTextView tvDateIvMemes;
    public RelativeLayout layoutMemes;
    //News
    TextView tvNews;
    CardView btnNews;
    //Twitch
    AppCompatTextView viewrsTwitch ;
    AppCompatTextView languageTwitch;
    AppCompatTextView statusTwitch;
    CircleImageView profileTwitch;
    AppCompatImageView imageViewTwitch ;
    AppCompatTextView tvNameTwitch ;
    RelativeLayout urlLayoutTwitch ;
    SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        switch (code){
            case 1:
                timeEvent = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_event);
                tvPrizeEvent = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_prize);
                tvGameModeEvent = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_gamemode);
                tvBuyInEvent = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_buy_in);
                tvLateRegEvent = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_late_reg);
                tvSiteEvent = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_site);
                ivEvent = (AppCompatImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_events);
                layoutEvent = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.events_layout);
                return;
            case 2:
                tvNews = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_tv);
                btnNews = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_news);
                return;
            case 3:
                ivMemes = (AppCompatImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_world_news_iv);
                tvIvMemes = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_world_news_iv_tv);
                tvDateIvMemes = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_world_news_date_iv_tv);
                return;
            case 4:
                timeTourTours = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_tour);
                tvPrizeTours = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_prize);
                tvGameModeTours = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_gamemode);
                tvBuyInTours = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_buy_in);
                tvLateRegTours = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_late_reg);
                tvReBuyTours = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_rebuy);
                tvDaysTours = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_days);
                clockTours = (Clock) itemView.findViewById(R.id.clock);
                return;
            case 5:
                tvSites = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sites);
                headerImageSites = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_url_cover_image);
                btnRevilSites = (AppCompatImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_revil);
                infoTvSites = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_tv);
                infoDateSites = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_date);
                btnUrlSites = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_url);
                btnTelegramSites = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_telgram);
                btnSupportSites = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sup);
                layoutSites = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.revil);
                layour_btnSites = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_btn);
                btnRegSites = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
                return;
            case 6:
                urlLayoutTwitch = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.url_layout);
                statusTwitch = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.streamer_status);
                profileTwitch = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
                imageViewTwitch = (AppCompatImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.twitch_icon);
                tvNameTwitch = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.streamer_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have Single recyclerview in all of your tabs?

Comment: no 2 of them have another viewpager with 2 recyclerViews on them

Comment: What do you want to do ? Search by editText ?

Comment: no by the SearchView

Comment: Is your searchView is in Activity ? and you want result in Fragments ?

Comment: yea SearchView in Activity and i want to show result in a Dialog

Comment: Where is your Dialog ? Inside Activity ?

Comment: https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/MaterialDialogSearchView                   thanks a lot for helping me i want to use this library

Comment: By using this , What issue are you getting ?

Comment: i dont know how to add all of my items into a single RecyclerView i will edit my question please see my code

Comment: Here you are using same recyclerview adapter for all the reyclerview, How you will identify the reyclerview data .

Comment: with code int in constructor  do you have any better ways? please tell me

Comment: I have no codes , but i can give to suggestions

Comment: thanks a lot sorry for bad English but i want to show all of my adapters into one RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using 7 different `pojo` classes for all of your different `RecyclerView`. If you want to search by single `searchView` then you have to Add all of your `pojo` data to single `pojo` class. But if you add all of your data to single `pojo` result will come when you will search , but it will be difficult for you find that fragment.

If you want result for that viewPager fragment only. Then you have to implement same `searchView` for all  of your `pojo` classes, and you have to get result on that `fragment` only.

Comment: Add all pojo data to single pojo and perform search by that pojo only, so you will get search result by all of your data.

Comment: Welcome @Sadegh, Happy to help you